# How to put output into a list using loop?

Tags: python, list

I've been trying to make a list putting output values.

There is an `if` statement on the second line and that extracts some numbers following statement anyway, no matter what the numbers are, I'd like to make a list including these numbers.

```
list1 = []
if rowspan :
    for i in [n] : # n means result numbers filtered by if statement.
        list1.append(i)
print(list1)

this code shows so far :
[2]
[5]
[8]
[11]
[14]
```

If the numbers (`n`) are 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, I want to show the result like as :

list1 = `[2,5,8,11,14]` as a `list`.

Would you give me any advice?

Comment: can you explain better the request please? it looks like you are answering yourself with the question :)

Comment: Explain better please, does your code print a list of lists?

Comment: Can you please clarify what `rowspan` and `[n]` is? I'm sure your code has bugs in these two places. The rest seems quite okay.

Comment: rowspan is a kind of filter there are super long codes related rowspan so it's not that so easy to show all code

Comment: if i write as n instead of [n] results type error -> 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: `[n]` is a list with just one element, the value of `n`. You can replace the loop with just `list1.append(n)`.

Comment: `n` is just one number, where are all the different numbers supposed to come from?

Comment: but why does n not [n] results Typeerror? TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.